# How to archive selected text in Org?

Tags: org-mode

```
* Heading  
** Sub-heading  
*** Sub-sub-heading  
- plain text
- more plain text
- even more plain text
```

I want to select `- more plain text` and archive it with C-c, C-x, C-a.

I only want `- more plain text` to be archived. I want the headings and the rest of the plain text to stay in place.

When I try this, it archives everything.

Comment: Where in your archive file should `- more plain text` be placed -- at the very bottom of the archive file (at flush left) without any heading/subheading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend following the answer from @Tyler because it encourages using org-mode as designed.

However, if you're *absolutely determined to archive a list item* then:

**Try this**

1. Place point on *list item*
2. Move *list item* to bottom of the list using <kbd>M-down</kbd>.
3. Convert *list item* to heading using <kbd>C-c *</kbd>.
4. Archive header using <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd>

This should leave the original file that appears similar to this:

```
* Heading

** Sub-heading

*** Sub-sub-heading

- plain text
- even more plain text
```

and create an entry in archive file that is similar to this:

```
* more plain text
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ARCHIVE_TIME: 2016-11-16 Wed 11:27
  :ARCHIVE_FILE: /tmp/sx/emacs/how-to-archive-selected-text-in-org.org
  :ARCHIVE_OLPATH: Heading/Sub-heading/Sub-sub-heading
  :ARCHIVE_CATEGORY: how-to-archive-selected-text-in-org
  :END:
```

> **Note:** If you have any content under the header after your list **do not archive** or you'll archive more than you want too. This method only works on very simple use cases such as your example.

**Hope that helped!**

---

This answer was tested using

> GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.14.13)
>   org-mode version: 9.0

Comment: I will do this with some form of this: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28182/kill-and-yank-append-text-from-buffer-to-bottom-of-same-buffer

Answer (score 4):

Archiving is designed to work on trees or subtrees. i.e., the basic unit to be archived is a heading with all the nested content under that heading. You can't archive arbitrary text without the heading it belongs to. Otherwise, as @lawlist suggests in his question, there's no clearly defined place to archive the text. (and after you've archived one bit of text, where does the next bit go relative to the first bit you archived?)

You could probably code something yourself that would automatically transfer selected text to a particular location you specify, to 'archive' it. However, you'd be working against the expected workflow for org-mode. Using subheadings (which can be archived) or checkboxes (i.e., `- [ ]`) to indicate items that have been dealt with, might be more straightforward.